# How do I get the subway achievements?

Tags: edge

In EDGE, there are two achievements that refer to the subway, "Subway" (Ride the complete subway track) and "Turnstile jumper" (Evade the subway fare). What level do these refer to and how do I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The achievements are both on "metro" (normal level 10).

To get "Subway", ride on one of the moving blocks for each segment of the loop that those blocks take. The following is a video that shows how to get it:

To get "Turnstile jumper", at the point near the beginning where there are three switches that lower a barrier to the rest of the level, avoid the switches and climb over the nearby blocks. The following video shows how to get it:

Comment: I like how you answered your own question.